# function for matrix

Tags: r

I am learning R online and am working through some labs. 
I have the question:
 "write a recursive function which inverts any matrix using the block-wise inversion technique. Your function must not use the solve function (or any other inbuilt R matrix inversion/decomposition function)".

I have thought of trying QR or Choleski decomposition but both of these would be using an "inbuilt function". 
What sort of code would block-wise inversion involve?

Here is a sample matrix:

```
M1 = matrix(rnorm(120^2),120,120)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this, looking at wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion

```
getInverse <- function(mat) {

  if(nrow(mat) == 1)
  {
    return (matrix( 1.0/ mat[1,1] ))
  }

  idx <- nrow(mat) / 2
  A <- mat[1:idx, 1:idx, drop=F]
  B <- mat[1:idx, -1:-idx, drop=F]
  C <- mat[-1:-idx, 1:idx, drop=F]
  D <- mat[-1:-idx, -1:-idx, drop=F]

  invA <- getInverse(A)
  temp <- getInverse(D - C %*% invA %*% B)
  element11 <- invA + invA %*% B %*% temp %*% C %*% invA
  element12 <- -invA %*% B %*% temp
  element21 <- -temp %*% C %*% invA
  element22 <- temp

  result <- cbind(rbind(element11, element21), rbind(element12, element22))
}

set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3)
print("Function test:")
print(getInverse(mat))
print("Using Solve:")
solve(mat)
```

Update for the question in the comments:
I've chosen these names to match the 4 different elements, or blocks, on the wiki page block matrix inversion formula. I see the result as a matrix of matrices, thus element11 was chosen for row 1, column 1 and element21 for row 2, element 1. I didn't really 'work out' anything I just stored some intermediate calculations into variables. Finally, the result is built by combining the blocks.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It seems to run perfectly! Is there any chance you could explain the code a little bit because I am still not really sure how it was done

Comment: Hi I just follow the wiki page. If the matrix is 1x1 I return directly the inverse. This is also needed to escape the recursive part. Otherwise I split the matrix in blocks, similar to the wikipedia notation for A, B, C and D. The split is done in half. Then the formulas from the wiki page are used, calling the same getInverse function, which makes it recursive. element11 corresponds to the upper left block, etc. Finally I combine the blocks into the result.

Comment: Ok I think I understand most of it now :) Just one more question - how did you work out that "element11 corresponds to the upper left block, etc" Sorry for all the questions. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: To answer further questions in the comments, please just edit your answer and don't post an additional answer. I've just copied the second answer to this answer as the information provided there is helpful. The second answer will probably be deleted as it was flagged for deletion because it's not an answer.