# Recursive function for implementing block-wise inversion technique in R

Tags: r, recursion, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am very new to linear algebra and I am trying to implement a recursive function which inverts any matrix using
the block-wise inversion technique from scratch without using the R library "solve".

This question was already answer in the following post: [function for matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564606/function-for-matrix)

However, it did not work for me and I tried to implement my own version:

```
matrixInversion <- function(M){
   if(nrow(M) == 2){
      a <- M[1,1]
      b <- M[1,2]
      c <- M[2,1]
      d <- M[2,2]
      deter <- ((a*d)-(b*c))
      InverseMatrix <- ((1/deter)*matrix(c(d,-c,-b,a),nrow=2,ncol=2))
   } else {
      x <- (floor(nrow(M) / 2))
      A <- M[1:x, 1:x, drop=F]
      B <- M[1:x, -1:-x, drop=F]
      C <- M[-1:-x, 1:x, drop=F]
      D <- M[-1:-x, -1:-x, drop=F]

      Ainv <- matrixInversion(A)
      common <- matrixInversion(D - C %*% Ainv %*% B)
      newA <- Ainv+Ainv%*%B%*%common%*%C%*%Ainv
      newB <- (-Ainv)%*%B%*%common
      newC <- (-common)%*%C%*%Ainv
      newD <- (-common)

      result <- cbind(rbind(newA, newC), rbind(newB, newD))
    }
}
```

This version works successfully for matrix with even number of columns, but not with matrix with odd number of columns. I cannot understand how to implement it correctly. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide (a) sample data (both working and not-working), and (b) the error or failure? My first guess is that it has to do with `nrow(M) == 2`. With odd-rowcount matrices, the third call to `matrixInversion` sends a 1x1 matrix, failing your first conditional and attempting to partition the matrix again. (Using `<=` likely won't work, you may need another `} else if {` somewhere in there ...)

Comment: It works with: M = matrix(rnorm(4^2),4,4), but not with
M2 = matrix(rnorm(5^2),5,5).

Comment: Two things. (1) *"It works ... but not with ...".* By running the code locally, I think I know what is happening, but your question doesn't include what *you* are seeing. (2) Regardless, the problem is that your function mis-handles 1x1 matrices. Fix that and you should be good.

Comment: Hi! sorry, this is my output when I run the M2 = matrix(rnorm(5^2),5,5): Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: I also included an extra if for solving the 1x1 matrix by including this condition: if (nrow(M) == 1){
    InverseMatrix <- matrix(1/M)}, now the function run without issue, but the result is different from the one I get from solve. Is my formula wrong? thanks and sorry

Comment: Furthermore, it prints a matrix of NAN value for bigger matrix, like: matrix(rnorm(150^2),150,150).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to points made in the comments, you incorrectly negate `newD`. Your function with changes now works with both odd-row and even-row matrices:

```
matrixInversion <- function(M){
  if (nrow(M) == 1){
    return(1/M)
  } else if (nrow(M) == 2){
    a <- M[1,1]
    b <- M[1,2]
    c <- M[2,1]
    d <- M[2,2]
    deter <- ((a*d)-(b*c))
    return((1/deter)*matrix(c(d,-c,-b,a),nrow=2,ncol=2))
  } else {
    x <- (floor(nrow(M) / 2))
    A <- M[1:x, 1:x, drop=F]
    B <- M[1:x, -1:-x, drop=F]
    C <- M[-1:-x, 1:x, drop=F]
    D <- M[-1:-x, -1:-x, drop=F]
    Ainv <- matrixInversion(A)
    common <- matrixInversion(D - C %*% Ainv %*% B)
    newA <- Ainv+Ainv%*%B%*%common%*%C%*%Ainv
    newB <- (-Ainv)%*%B%*%common
    newC <- (-common)%*%C%*%Ainv
    newD <- common
    return(cbind(rbind(newA, newC), rbind(newB, newD)))
  }
}

## random seed not relevant here ...
m1 <- matrix(runif(150^2), nr=150)
all.equal(solve(m1), matrixInversion(m1))
# [1] TRUE
any(is.nan(matrixInversion(m1))) # based on your comment
# [1] FALSE

m2 <- matrix(runif(151^2), nr=151)
all.equal(solve(m2), matrixInversion(m2))
# [1] TRUE
any(is.nan(matrixInversion(m2)))
# [1] FALSE
```

For the record, I found this by incrementally checking larger matrices. Something like:

```
m1 <- matrix(runif(150^2), nr=150)
i <- 4; all.equal(solve(m1[1:i,1:i]), matrixInversion(m1[1:i,1:i]))
```

At 2, it was equal, and it started breaking above that. I used `debugonce(matrixInversion)` to check inside the first two conditional blocks, but they were fine. I then compared your equations with the originally-cited [wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion), and noticed your incorrect calculation. Of course, it was the last one I checked :-)